# DROOLS+ springboot+gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, drools

I have added the dependencies for drools in my build.gradle file.

```
implementation group: 'org.kie', name: 'kie-api', version: '7.16.0.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-core', version: '7.16.0.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-compiler', version: '7.16.0.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.kie', name: 'kie-spring', version: '7.16.0.Final'
```

I can't understand the steps to proceed the project to write a rule in drools. please help me to know what should i do to write a rule in drools.(should i install plugins in drools and kie)

Comment: Well, first I would recommend reading the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/). Then you can proceed in writing a test rule file (drl) and adding it to your classpath, along with a kmodule xml. The documentation explains all of this, though.

Comment: Thank you. I'm refering the documentation now.

Comment: If you are confused about a specific part of the process, you can ask about that part of the process, showing your attempt. But the documentation is quite thorough.